# An error occurred for Current measurement with ESP32s and PZEM004T v2

Tags: arduino, iot, esp32

I'm using ESP32s and PZEM004T V2.0 for the current measurement project.
While executing I get the following error:

```
esptool.py v3.0-dev
Serial port COM5
Connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "esptool.py", line 3682, in <module>
  File "esptool.py", line 3675, in _main
  File "esptool.py", line 3330, in main
  File "esptool.py", line 512, in connect
  File "esptool.py", line 492, in _connect_attempt
  File "esptool.py", line 431, in sync
  File "esptool.py", line 369, in command
  File "esptool.py", line 332, in write
  File "site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 323, in write
serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout
Failed to execute script esptool
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: What do you think "An error occurred while uploading the sketch" might mean?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're running on a windows box. Make sure that your esp32 is connected to a working USB socket on your machine (I have a couple that work for everything except arduino). Make sure you have the correct COM port selected - one esp32 might be COM5 and another might be COM6, and yes, the bindings may persist. I'm currently up to COM54 or something on my machine. Make sure you haven't screwed up your wiring somewhere. If you've shorted your circuit somewhere, nothing is going to make that processor available. And.... it's always possible that you've fried the thing by hitting it with too much voltage/current for it to handle. Your title does mention current measurement - are you sure the esp32 is still functional? (Is your old code running on it and doing something to indicate so?)